# Difference between <=> and == in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, spaceship-operator

What are their differences? Coming from a Java background, it does seem to me <=> is the same as Java's equals(), while == is for direct reference comparison. Is this right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`==` only measures if two objects are equal, whereas `<=>` should return -1 if the first object is smaller, 0 if they are equal, and 1 if the first object is greater.

If you define a `<=>` method for your class, you'll get all of the other comparison operators defined as well (`==`, `<`, `>`, and so on).

Comment: Ah, so <=> is like Java's compareTo() method?

Answer (score 3):

Can't say I'm not trying to promote myself, but I wrote a full length tutorial about comparison and equality operators in Ruby: ["Ruby Basics – Equality operators in Ruby"](http://techbot.me/2011/05/ruby-basics-equality-operators-ruby/)

In there you can see the differences between all the equality operators, including <=>, == and === (and the implications of implementing them, including the hash method implementation).

Answer (score 2):

`==` is like Java's `equals`, while `<=>` is like `compareTo`. `==` compares the two objects and returns whether they are equivalent. `a <=> b` compares the two objects and returns 1 if `a` is bigger, 0 if they are the same and `-1` if `b` is bigger.